Issue with VPC Service Controls and Ingress Policy on Google Cloud
In our organization, we have configured an Access Policy with a scope for a GCP folder.
Here are the details of our configuration:

Access Policy:

Name: accessPolicies/XXXXX
Scope: GCP Folder


Access Level:

Name: accessLevels/Access_Level_Restriction
Filter: Authorized public IPs


VPC Service Perimeter in Dry Run mode:

Name: servicePerimeters/vpc_perimeter
Resources to protect:

Projects: All GCP projects in the GCP folder
Networks: All VPCs of the protected GCP projects


Restricted Services: All services
VPC Accessible Services: N/A
Access Levels: N/A
Ingress Policy:

From: Any Identity (Source: Access Level: Access_Level_Restriction)
To: All projects, All services


Egress Policy:

From: Any Identity
To: All projects, All services





We have enabled the VPC SC / WIF feature for our organization.
Issue Encountered:
When connected via Workforce Identity Federation (WIF) or Cloud Identity, I can access Compute Engine to list instances in the GCP project project_id. However, when filtering logs with log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/policy") AND severity="error" AND protoPayload.metadata.dryRun="true", I receive VPC Service Controls errors in Dry Run mode stating:
(Dry Run Mode) Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier: XXXXXXX
Error Details:
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog [invalid URL removed]",
    "status": {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "(Dry Run Mode) Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier: XXXXXXX",
      "details": 
        {
          "@type": "[type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure [invalid URL removed]",
          "violations": [
            {
              "type": "VPC_SERVICE_CONTROLS",
              "description": "XXXXXXX"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "anonymized_email@domain.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "MY_IPV4",
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "compute.beta.ProjectsService.Get",
    "resourceName": "projects/XXXXXXXXX",
    "metadata": {
      "deviceState": "Unknown",
      "ingressViolations": [
        {
          "servicePerimeter": "accessPolicies/XXXXX/servicePerimeters/vpc_perimeter",
          "targetResource": "projects/XXXXXXXXX"
        }
      ],
      "intermediateServices": [
        "cloudclient-pa.googleapis.com"
      ],
      "securityPolicyInfo": {
        "organizationId": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "servicePerimeterName": "accessPolicies/XXXXX/servicePerimeters/vpc_perimeter"
      },
      "vpcServiceControlsUniqueId": "XXXXXXX",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.VpcServiceControlAuditMetadata [invalid URL removed]",
      "dryRun": true,
      "resourceNames": [
        "project_id"
      ],
      "violationReason": "NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "resource": {
    "type": "audited_resource",
    "labels": {
      "method": "compute.beta.ProjectsService.Get",
      "service": "compute.googleapis.com",
      "project_id": "project_id"
    }
  }

Questions:

Why does this error appear even though the IP is authorized in the ingress policy?
Is it necessary to explicitly add the access level in the service perimeter despite the configuration via the ingress policy?


Why does this error appear even though the IP is authorized in the ingress policy?
This should be connected on group policy to allow explicitly the access level, link
Is it necessary to explicitly add the access level in the service perimeter despite the configuration via the ingress policy?
It is recommended to explicitly add the access level in service parameter as described in this link

Hey Ron etch , the links you provided are mine I just forgot to repost the answer here thanks anyway
